# real-time BigQuery usage stats in https://console.developers.google.com/home/dashboard

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to see the real-time BigQuery usage in https://console.developers.google.com/home/dashboard?

We have a shared project with many users and wanted to see how many other processes were running.  It seems that BQ slows down during peak times (9am-5pm) and my queries run faster at non peak times (e.g. weekends, late night).

1) Is there a processing quota assigned to each project? It could be that BQ is just slower during those times due to higher usage across all BQ users in the US.

2) If so, is there a way to monitor it in real-time?  I can monitor compute engine and app engine usage but wanted to see BQ usage too if possible.

Answer (score 2):

In response to your question #1, yes, there is a processing quota assigned to each project. There is generally enough capacity that behavior of other users shouldn't affect the amount of resources your project receives. However, if you're running a lot of queries, you can certainly start to see a slowdown as your project gets throttled.

If you need more quota for more consistent performance, you can purchase 'reserved slots'. More information [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#slots).

Answer (score 2):

Audit logs for your project might be useful.  It allows you to see a log of queries and other requests made to BigQuery, which could help determine what rate you're sending certain requests.  More info can be found in [our documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, last 1 Hour duration is as realtime as it gets.stats can be seen at

```
APIs -> Enabled APIs -> BigQuery API -> Usage
```

Comment: Thanks for youtr help

Comment: Note that this only shows calls to the BQ API, not charges for BQ queries and storage.